# HDFS vs HIVE partitioning

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera, partitioning

This may be a simple thing but i'm struggling to find the answer. When the data is loaded to HDFS its distributed and loaded into multiple nodes. The data is partitioned and distributed. 
For HIVE there is a separate option to PARTITION the data. I'm pretty sure that even if you don't mention the PARTITION option, the data will be split and distributed to different nodes on the cluster, when loading a hive table.  What additional benefit does this command give in this case.

Comment: Distribution has nothing to do with it (partitioning). It is the exact same concept as in a local file system.

Comment: Partitioning stores the data in a sub-directory for each partition. When you filter by a partitioning column, hive will only scan the sub-directories that are specified in your filter, which will give you better performance.  As @DuduMarkovitz said, this is completely unrelated to HDFS data distribution and replication.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. When you are loading the data into hive table data is segmented or partitioned into blocks and saved on different nodes in the cluster. My assumption is that even partitioning the data does the same thing. Even though data is arranged in folders and sub folders when PARTITIONED in HIVE, its still saved as blocks in the HDFS. If so what is partitioning doing in this case. What additional benefit is it providing.

Comment: Same question, same answer. What is the benefit from partitions on "standard" databases?

Comment: Ok got it. When we run a query i think it will scan only the blocks related to the particular partition that we are interested in, rather than going through all of them. I think the data will be shuffled with in the blocks to accommodate data related to those partitions.

Comment: True for the first part. I didn't get the second part.

Comment: Lets say the data related to a particular country like USA is spread across multiple blocks in different nodes randomly. After partitioning, the data will be shuffled and stored again so that the information about the USA can be retrieved from few blocks rather than scanning every block of that table. Am i right?

Comment: Once again, distribution is not relevant here. If the files containning USA records are in the same directory with all the other files, then you have no indication which file contain USA records and which not, therefor you have to scan all files in order to find USA records.  If the files containning USA records are in a separate directory, then obviously you can scan only the files in that directory. It doesn't matter if a "file" in that directory in a sequence of blocks in the same node of sequence of blocks distributed between different nodes.

Comment: Oh Alright. Looks like partitioning is logical and it acts more like an index for finding the information related to a country or what ever key you defining while partitioning. It has nothing to do with physical storage. Is that right? Thanks Dudu for patiently answering my question.

Comment: Getting closer :-) (1) let's keep indexes out of this discussion (2) Physical storage does matter in one basic aspect: a block will only contain the rows of a single partition. This means that you never read a row from unwanted partition. This also means that you cannot partition over more than one set of columns.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

summarizing comments and for Hadoop v1-v2.x:

- a logical partitioning, eg. related to a date or field in a string, as written in the comments above, is only possible in hive, hcat or a another sql or parallel engine working on top of hadoop, using a fileformat which supports partitioning (Parquet, ORC, CSV are ok, but eg. XML is hard or nearly impossible to partition)
- logical partitioning (like in hive, hcat) can be used as a replacement for not having an indexes
- 'partitioning of hdfs storage' on local or distributed nodes is possible by defining the partitions during setup of hdfs, see https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_cluster-planning/content/ch_partitioning_chapter.html
- HDFS is able to "balance" or 'distribute' blocks over nodes
- Natively, blocks can't be split and distributed to folders by HDFS according to their content, only moved at whole to another node
- blocks (not files!) are replicated in the HDFS cluster according to the HDFS replication factor:

  ```
  $ hdfs fsck /
  ```

(thanks David and Kris for your discussion above, also explains most of it and please take this post as summary)

Answer (score 1):

HDFS partition : Mainly deals with the storage of files on the node. For fault tolerance, files are replicated across the cluster( Using replication factor)

Hive partition : It's an optimization technique in Hive.
Inside Hive DB, while storing tables and for better performance on the queries we go for partitioning.
Partitioning gives information about how data is stored in hive and how to read the data.
Hive Partitioning can be controlled on the column level of the table data.